# Почему не воспроизводится строки из листбокса взятые из файла?

Tags: python-3.x, файлы, gui, tkinter

**Цель программы** пользователь указывает директория Где расположены его музыка в listbox попадают только .MP3 файлы, далее при нажатии в listbox и на нужный файл и на кнопку плей он воспроизводится, после того программа сохраняет файлы путь который пользователь указал и при каждом новом ее запуска
Берутся строки (пути) из Сохраненного программой файл и вводится в listbox, и пользователю показываются директории из файла.

**Ошибка, проблема в программе** Программа Работает хорошо до того момента когда ей надо считывать информацию из файла то есть при повторном запуске программы она считывает из файла информацию правильно и все директории в файле тоже Правильные но всё-равно трек не воспроизводится, внизу будет прикрепленный код.

**Код ошибки:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py”, line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File “SMPMGI.py”, line 63, in selct_file
Play_Treak(selcted_file)
File “SMPMGI.py”, line 48, in Play_Treak
mixer.music.load(selcted_file)
pygame.error: Couldn't open 'C:Users/Koder1554/Music/WATCH DOGS SONG - Digital Shadow.mp3
```

**Код программы:**

```
#import's ####################
import os
import os.path
import tkinter
from pygame import mixer
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
##############################
#installize icon's and files####################
MGI = tkinter.Tk()
MGI.title("LISTER ATV 0.0.3")
MGI.geometry('640x500')
pryoimge1 = PhotoImage(file = "folde1r.png")
pryoimge2 = PhotoImage(file = "mp_btns_play.png")
pryoimge3 = PhotoImage(file = "mp_btns_next.png")
pryoimge4 = PhotoImage(file = "mp_btns_prev.png")
pryoimge5 = PhotoImage(file = "mp_btns_pause.png")
PathSelect_button_icon = pryoimge1.subsample(8,8)
PlayTreak_button_icon = pryoimge2.subsample(10,10)
past_treak_icon = pryoimge4.subsample(10,10)
Next_treak_icon = pryoimge3.subsample(10,10)
Pause_treak_icon = pryoimge5.subsample(10,10)
#################################################
#func's
#if 'savepath.txt' not exsist "run this funcshin"
#make list with only .mp3 files and write/rwrite file if not crate#
def mp3_listbox1(dirctory):
            f = open("savepath.txt", 'w', encoding='utf-8')
            for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dirctory):
                for x in filenames:
                    if ".mp3" in x:
                        mp3_listbox.insert(END, dirpath + "/" + x)
                        f.write(dirpath + "/" + x + "\n")
##################################################################
#play select treak###############
def Play_Treak(selcted_file):
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load(selcted_file)
    mixer.music.play()
##################################
#Select folder and file diolog##########
def Select_folder():
    dirctory = filedialog.askdirectory()
    mp3_listbox1(dirctory)
#######################################
#file selecting(get) in list to play func#
def selct_file():
    selcted_file = mp3_listbox.get(ACTIVE)
    Play_Treak(selcted_file)
##########################################
#past treak select(List box clicked element)#
def past_select():
    z = mp3_listbox.index(ACTIVE)
    mp3_listbox.selection_clear(z)
    mp3_listbox.select_set(z-1)
    mp3_listbox.activate(z-1)
    mp3_listbox.selection_anchor(z-1)
    selct_file()
############################################
#Next treak select(get new list elements)###
def next_select():
    z = mp3_listbox.index(ACTIVE)
    mp3_listbox.selection_clear(z)
    mp3_listbox.select_set(z+1)
    mp3_listbox.activate(z+1)
    mp3_listbox.selection_anchor(z+1)
    selct_file()
############################################
#interface button's, Listsbox, and check if file 'savepath.txt' exists###################
PathSelect_button = Button(MGI,  image = PathSelect_button_icon ,command = Select_folder)
PlayTreak_button = Button(MGI, image = PlayTreak_button_icon,command =selct_file)
mp3_listbox = Listbox(MGI, width  = 200 , height = 55)
past_treak = Button(MGI, image = past_treak_icon, command = past_select)
Next_treak = Button(MGI, image = Next_treak_icon, command = next_select)
Pause_treak = Button(MGI, image = Pause_treak_icon)
check_file = os.path.exists('savepath.txt')
if check_file == True:
    f = open("savepath.txt", 'r',encoding='utf-8')
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        mp3_listbox.insert(END, line)
        line = f.readline() 
##########################################################################################


#placing buttons, list's. and most witdgts##### 
PathSelect_button.place(x = 10, y = 1)
mp3_listbox.place(x =  20, y = 100)
PlayTreak_button.place(x = 10,  y= 56)
past_treak.place(x = 55, y = 56)
Next_treak.place(x = 100, y = 56)
Pause_treak.place(x = 144, y = 56)
######################################
#run tkinter
MGI.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда программа считывает имена mp3-файлов в виде строк из текстового файла, то они читаются вместе с символом конца строки `\n`. Из-за этого в дальнейшем возникает ошибка.
Чтобы этого избежать можно после чтения очередной строки удалять из неё символ `\n` с помощью метода [rstrip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip):

```
if check_file == True:
    f = open("savepath.txt", 'r',encoding='utf-8')
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        line = line.rstrip("\n") # Удаляем символ конца строки
        mp3_listbox.insert(END, line)
        line = f.readline()
```